# parse text file line by line then put matching string into an array then output to csv file

Tags: perl

Input text file as below. I called it `$rlseHistRepo`.

```
Route:  TUCSON-AZ
Author: upham
Date:   2018-06-07 20:09:17 UTC
Release:0.0
Content:
        Full Release
Comment:
        Initial setup

*** Modified on Mon Jun 11 19:18:40 PDT 2018 by upham ***
QRC Acceptor: Admin
Log: http://universityofarizona/ECE101/rev0.0_060718_130854-4307-1528769914.qclog
Successful
Status: {Objects succeeded (1)} {}
--------------------------------------------------
Route:  YUMA-AZ
Author: upham
Date:   2018-06-07 20:09:18 UTC
Release:0.0
Content:
        Full Release
Comment:
        Initial setup

*** Modified on Tue Sep 25 15:40:02 PDT 2018 by upham ***
QRC Acceptor: Admin
Log: http://universityofarizona/ECE101/rev0.0_060718_130854-4307-1537915198.qclog
Successful 
Status: {Objects succeeded (33)} {}
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a perl script to parse the input file above and output to a csv file but I ran into issue with the hash and array which I am lacking of knowledge of manipulating data in the array. 
The key here is to get 
Here is what find line begins with 
Route:
Author:
Date:
Release:
Log:
Status:
Content:
Comments:
info then get the string thereafter and write out to csv file

Here is my starting script and I am struggling get the csv printout array properly. Appreciate your help to correct it and point out where and why the array didn't get printout properly in order.
Thank you very much in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$rlseHistRepo   = $ARGV[0];

my %menu;
open(IN, "< $rlseHistRepo" ) || die "cannot read input file: $!\n";
open(OUTCSV , "> rlseLoggingRepo.csv" ) || die "cannot write output file: $!\n";
print OUTCSV "Site,Author,Release,Date,Version,Changes,Comment\n";
print OUTCSV ",,,,,,,\n";

while(<IN> ) {
    my $line = $_;
    chomp($line);
    if( $line =~ m/^Route:/) {
    my ($item, $rlsSite) = split(/\s+/, $line);
    $menu{$item} = $rlsSite;
    }
    if( $line =~ m/^Author:/) {
    my ($item, $rlsAuthor) = split(/\s+/, $line);
    $menu{$item} = $rlsAuthor;
    }

} 
close(IN);

foreach $item ( keys %menu ) {
    print OUTCSV "$menu{$item},,,,,\n";
    print "$rlsSite{$item},$rlsAuthor{$item},,,,\n";
} 

close(OUTCSV);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm sorry, but I don't quite follow your expected output. Can you show an example of exactly what you want your output CSV to look like?

Comment: Please make sure to `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, and I recommend using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to render your CSV output. The `csv` function it provides is the simplest way to write an array of hashes to a CSV file, or you can use the object interface for more control.

Comment: Obvious errors in your script after adding `use strict;`: (a) `%rlsSite` not defined, (b) `%rlsAuthor` not defined, (c) your last `print` is missing OUTCSV (I guess its output should go to the CSV?)

Answer (score 0):

As you have not specified what the output should actually look like, I took a stab in the dark and made a guess by looking at the input data and your regexes.

For production quality code please follow the advice of @Grinnz to use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) instead.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Entry,Site,Author,Release,Date,Version,Changes,Comment\n";

my @entries;
while(<DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    if (my($site) = /^Route:\s+(.+)$/) {
        # start of new entry
        push(@entries, {
            site => $site,
        });
    } elsif (my($author) = /^Author:\s+(.+)$/) {
        $entries[-1]->{author} = $author;
    }
}

foreach my $index (0..$#entries) {
    my $entry = $entries[$index];
    print "$index,$entry->{site},$entry->{author},,,,,\n";
}

__DATA__
Route:  TUCSON-AZ
Author: upham
Date:   2018-06-07 20:09:17 UTC
Release:0.0
Content:
        Full Release
Comment:
        Initial setup

*** Modified on Mon Jun 11 19:18:40 PDT 2018 by upham ***
QRC Acceptor: Admin
Log: http://universityofarizona/ECE101/rev0.0_060718_130854-4307-1528769914.qclog
Successful
Status: {Objects succeeded (1)} {}
--------------------------------------------------
Route:  YUMA-AZ
Author: upham
Date:   2018-06-07 20:09:18 UTC
Release:0.0
Content:
        Full Release
Comment:
        Initial setup

*** Modified on Tue Sep 25 15:40:02 PDT 2018 by upham ***
QRC Acceptor: Admin
Log: http://universityofarizona/ECE101/rev0.0_060718_130854-4307-1537915198.qclog
Successful 
Status: {Objects succeeded (33)} {}
--------------------------------------------------
```

Example run:

```bash
$ perl dummy.pl
Entry,Site,Author,Release,Date,Version,Changes,Comment
0,TUCSON-AZ,upham,,,,,
1,YUMA-AZ,upham,,,,,
```

**EDIT:** an alternative approach would be to use

```perl
if (/^Route:/../^----------/) {
    # we are inside a log entry...
}
```

and then detect

- keyword lines with `my($keyword, $data) = /^(\w+):\s*(.*)$/;`
- text lines with `my($line) = /^\s+(.+)$/;`

inside that block.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add `use strict` and `use warnings`. This throws up errors about undeclared variables.

Step 2: Add `my` to declare `$rlseHistRepo`. Also add `my (%rlsSite, %rlsAuthor)` to declare two hashes used in your final loop. But that's weird as you're reading values from those hashes without every storing data in them. This gives us a few "uninitialized value" errors. So I think we're going to need to rethink things.

The idea is going to be to build one hash for each record. And when the record is ended (when we get a line of dashes) we output that record. Something like this:

```
my @keys = qw[Route Author Date Release Log
              Status Content Comment];

my %record;

while(<IN> ) {
  chomp;
  if (/-----/) {
    say OUTCSV join ',', @record{@keys};
    %record = ();
  }

  # ignore lines without a ':'
  next unless /:/;
  # ignore the '***' lines
  next if /\*\*\*/;

  my ($key, $value) = split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2);
  # Some keys have their values on the next line
  if ($value !~ /\S/) {  
    chomp($value = <IN>);
    $value =~ s/^\s+//;
  } 
  $record{$key} = $value;
}
```

Step 3: Clean things up a bit by removing a few unnecessary variables and making it into a Unix filter (reading from `STDIN` and writing to `STDOUT`) - this is actually easier to write and makes your program far more flexible.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @keys = qw[Route Author Date Release Log
              Status Content Comment];

say "Site,Author,Release,Date,Version,Changes,Comment";
say ",,,,,,,";

my %record;

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  if (/-----/) {
    say join ',', @record{@keys};
    %record = ();
  }

  # ignore lines without a ':'
  next unless /:/;
  # ignore the '***' lines
  next if /\*\*\*/;

  if (my ($key, $value) = split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2) {
    # Some keys have their values on the next line
    if ($value !~ /\S/) {
      chomp($value = <>);
      $value =~ s/^\s+//;
    }
    $record{$key} = $value;
  }
}
```

As others have mentioned, in production code you'd want to use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to produce the output.

Comment: Hi Dave and all,